# Align a set of views to the right of the largest view of those appearing in the right part of the screen

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-view, android-constraintlayout

Can I use a `ConstraintLayout` to create a view that aligns children views to based on the largest child view?
Example:
[image]

Taking into account that the right `Text` printed can be larger in one of the rows, I'd like to have the progress bars be aligned to the largest `Text` on the right.
Is that possible? I can do it with nested `LinearLayout` but was wondering if `ConstraintLayout` solves this

Comment: Yes you can achieve this by using constraint layout or Relativelaout. In Relativelayout align text to the allignparenEnd and progress bar to the startof text

Comment: @Raza: But in that case each progressbar will align to the text to its right while I want the progress bars to be aligned top-to-bottom with each other *and* align to the text with the bigger size

Comment: are you using list items to be displayed. Or this is the static view with these items.?

Comment: @Raza: Static views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `Barrier` with `start` direction and reference all the IDs of the `TextViews` on the right. Constrain the `end` of each progress bar to the `Barrier`. The `Barrier` will be aligned to the start of the longest `TextView`.

Sample XML of how to achieve this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/barrier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barrierDirection="start"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="text1,text2"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/progress1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ProgressBar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/barrier" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/progress2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ProgressBar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/progress1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/barrier" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Longer Text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result:
[image: result]

To prevent the left `TextView` from overlapping with other `Views` you need to constrain its `end` to progress bar, set horizontal bias to `0` so that it's aligned to its `start` constraint and also set `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` to its constraints are enforced when the width is set to `wrap_content`. It should look like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/foo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Foo"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/progress1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

It will cause the text to wrap to the next line when it reaches the progress bar. You can add ellipsis or limit the `TextView` to have the maximum of 1 line if you don't want the text to wrap.

Alternatively, you can just set the left `TextView's` width to `0` so it takes all available space to the left of the progress bar.

Comment: This seems to kind of work but the problem I have now is that if the `Foo` text in the left side is too long it overlaps the progressbars. I think I need some kind of way to stop the textview from overlapping

Comment: If the text is too long it indeed wraps, but in the preview the top of the wrapped text goes above the parent `ConstraintLayout` and looks as being cut off

Comment: Have you set the `top` constraint?

Comment: I have set the top and bottom to align with the top and bottom of the progressbar on the right so that it is centered